# How to show a success message on screen, after successful action in controller Java?

Tags: java, html, model-view-controller

I have an action in controller that is sending emails, when button is clicked. I want to show a message to the users to notify when all the emails are sent.

```
@Action(value = "sendRequest", results = { @Result(name = SUCCESS, location = "mail.jsp"),
            @Result(name = ERROR, location = "mail.jsp")})
public class MailController {

    public String sendMails() {

        //code where the mails are sending to users

        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

```
<div>
    <span class="button"><input type="button"
    id="_mailAll" class="buttonMails" value="Send" /></span>
</div>
```

```
$('#_mailAll').click(function () {
        var form = $('#_dashboardForm') ;
        form.attr('action', 'sendEmails.action');
        form.submit();
});
```

Comment: Just ditch JSP (as long as you don't have to work with it due to your application being a legacy one) and switch to JSF. [JSP technology is considered to be a deprecated presentation technology for JavaServer Faces](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html)

Comment: I have to work with JSP, that's how the project is developed

Comment: What library are you using here for your MVC?

Comment: Spring Framework